# Clone a flashdrive

Tags: flash, usb-drive, clone

How do you clone a bootable flashdrive? What Linux software can clone a flash drive. I tried doing a sector by sector copy using a Windows application which worked but the Linux flash drive doesn't boot up.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just clone using command line, eg.

`sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdd bs=4M && sync`

which datadumps from input file (if=) device sdc to output file (of=) device sdd, bs= is the number of bytes copied at a time.

After it completes it syncs (forces write out of any unwritten buffers [still in memory]) to allow removal.

Of course change sdc & sdd to be what is appropriate

note: the `sync` shouldn't be necessary; I probably use it to make me feel safer :)

Comment: Good answer but I would set size at 1.6 GB, or whatever the .ISO, is to save time on other 14.4, or 30.4 or 61.4 GB of empty space. Also in case source device is larger than target device. But I haven't tried it myself...

Answer (score 1):

As another answer says, you should use `dd` for this. Get the devices' file paths (they will be something like `/dev/sd[letter of the alphabet]`). You can do this using `lsblk`, which will show a tree of devices, partitions, and their respective sizes. If you're copying between two disks that are the same size, unplug one and see which disappears to make sure you don't mix the source and destination up.

After you have the devices' paths, use

`dd if='/dev/[path of input (source) device]' of='/dev/[path of output (destination) device]' bs=4M`.

The `bs=4m` tells `dd` to read 4mb at a time. This is generally a good number, but you might change it to fit your devices' read and write speeds when you're moving huge files. The greatest common denominator of the two write speeds should be used. But for small operations 4mb is probably fine.

In summary:

- Run `lsblk` to get the file paths of your devices
- Use `dd if='/dev/[source file/device path]' of='/dev/[destination file/device path] bs=4m`
- Change the `bs=4m` to suit your needs if you're copying a huge file.